# Store 2D image as an 1D array / Store 2D Matrix as a 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

So according to many posts, saying that if creating a 2D matrix(array), it's best to create them in 1 dimensional, and use some simple math to convert an index of a 2D to a 1D index.

This is not only faster and more space efficient.

Also, in OpenCV, there's a function (*.isContinuous()*: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-iscontinuous) for you to check the image you read are stored as continuously or not.

If yes, when looping through each pixel in the image would be more efficient.

I wonder if OpenCV stores an image 1 dimensionally, how do they manage to show the image correctly when showing the image?

Does the show function in OpenCV reshapes the image from 1D to 2D?  Or how do they manage to show 1D data in 2D form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Computer memory is just a one dimensional array of bytes, so there's always some kind of mapping involved. The `Mat` stores metadata, such as number of dimensions, size, step, number of channels, type of elements, etc. The documentation specifies the mapping between array coordinates and memory addresses. These two together are used to correctly interpret the data.

Comment: IMHO you're misinterpreting `isContinuous` somewhat. The underlying memory storage for `Mat` data is always a single, continuous chunk of memory. However, there's also a `step` member, which specifies the distance between the beginning of consecutive rows. This may be more than the number of columns (e.g. when the `Mat` is a ROI of some bigger array, or perhaps for alignment reasons), in which case you need to skip some constant number of elements at the end of each row. There's no array of individually allocated arrays representing individual rows.